# Where are all the Java SE specifications?

Tags: java, specifications

I found a java language specification in the Oracle site here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ 
But I noticed that the java language specification doesn't cover annotation and javabeans. Are  annotation and javabeans belongs to the concepts of Java EE or Java SE?
Where can I find all the specifications about the Java Languages? I want to learn all the stuff of Java from the specs.

BTW: I only get a link from google of the javabeans specification here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html. But this javabeans spec was released about 17 years ago. Is it really the latest javabeans spec?

Thanks.

Comment: Javabeans are not part of the spec, they are a mere convention. About annotations search for "java language specification 3rd edition"

Comment: @morgano Javabeans is not just a convention, it also has a spec (as linked in the question).

Comment: Nothing much has changed in the `JavaBeans` world in 17 years!

Comment: I know that specification, too old BTW, true is no one (or almost no one) use that spec to write what we nowadays know as javabeans, (for instance, register/remove listeners) and they are not part of the language spec.

Comment: See [JSR 336: JavaTM SE 7 Release Contents](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336)

Answer (score 5):

Annotations are covered in [JLS 9.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) and [JLS 9.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7). The JavaBeans spec is [elsewhere](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)

> But this javabeans spec was released about 17 years ago. Is it really the latest javabeans spec?

Yes.

By the way, I sincerely applaud your efforts to read the specs. The world would be a better place if more programmers read the spec for the languages they use<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: And in general, actually read the documentation.